# Rearranging other views in HorizontalScrollView when size of one view changes

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, android-view, horizontalscrollview

I am drawing a rectangles views and arranging it in HorizontalScrollView. I want a functionality such that when a rectangle(view) is clicked, it will grow in size but other rectangles(views) size should remain as it is.

I have a class LockHorizontalScrollview which draws the initial view by calling getView() method of CustomListAdapter class. Also, I am attaching onClicklistener in getView() method.

So when any view is clicked, I am redrawing all the views of HorizontalScrollView. But I am facing one problem, how do I tell the LockHorizontalScrollview(this class will draw all my views) class to redraw all the views again.

The problem I am facing is when I click any view, the application crashes

LockHorizontalScrollview class is called by main activity.This class call the getView() method of custom Adapter to draw all views. This class draw all views.

```
public class LockHorizontalScrollview extends HorizontalScrollView {
    Context context;
    int prevIndex = 0;
    int data[] = new int[] {200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200};

    CustomListAdapter kk;
    void  changedata(int position)
    {
        data[position]+=50;
        abc(kk);

    }




    public void setAdapter(Context context, CustomListAdapter mAdapter) {

        try {
            this.kk=mAdapter;
            fillViewWithAdapter(mAdapter);
        } catch (ZeroChildException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void fillViewWithAdapter(CustomListAdapter mAdapter)
            throws ZeroChildException {
        if (getChildCount() == 0) {
            throw new ZeroChildException(
                    "CenterLockHorizontalScrollView must have one child");
        }
        if (getChildCount() == 0 || mAdapter == null)
        {       Log.e("Ronak","Came at zero");
            return;
        }

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        //parent.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            parent.addView(mAdapter.getView(i, null, parent));
        }
    }

    void abc(CustomListAdapter mAdapter)
    {
        Log.e("Ronak","Came at");
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);

        //parent.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            parent.addView(mAdapter.getViewType(i, null, parent,data[i]));
        }
    }


}
```

My custom adapter is

```
    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

     static class ViewHolder {
            public DrawView drawview;
            public TextView textview;
            public LinearLayout ll;
        }

    private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context c;

    HorizontalScrollViewActivity abc=new HorizontalScrollViewActivity();
    //CenterLockHorizontalScrollview abc=new CenterLockHorizontalScrollview(c, null);
    private TreeSet<Integer> mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();


    public CustomListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> data) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mData=data;
        this.c=c;
    }

    public void addItem(final String item) {
        mData.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private int getWidth(String aa)
    {
        int k=aa.length();
        if(k>0 && k<=3)
            return 200;
        if(k>3 && k<=6)
            return 250;
        if(k>6 && k<=9)
            return 300;
        if(k>9 && k<=12)
            return 350;
        if(k>12 && k<=15)
            return 400;
        if(k>15 && k<=18)
            return 450;
        if(k>18 && k<=21)
            return 500;
        if(k>21 && k<=24)
            return 550;
        if(k>24 && k<=27)
            return 600;

        return 700;

    }

    private int getHeight(String aa)
    {

        return 350;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("Ronak","Came at getview");

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item,null);
                        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                        //final LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,400);
                        //layout.setLayoutParams(parms);
                           TextView t= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                        //t.setWidth(width);
                        //t.setBackgroundColor(0x7F2626);
                        holder.textview = t;
                        holder.ll=layout;
                        DrawView abc = (DrawView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawview);
                        holder.drawview=abc;
                        Log.e("Ronak","reached here3");            
                        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textview.setText(mData.get(position));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(c, "Clicked on="+position, 2).show();
            // Log.e
             abc.get().changedata(position);

                }
        });

        return convertView;
        }

    public View getViewType(final int position,  View convertView, final ViewGroup parent, int width) {
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item,null);
                        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,150);
                        layout.setLayoutParams(parms);

        return convertView;
        }
```

There is also DrawView.java class which draw a rectangle

and my xml news_list_item.xml which is layout of each view of Horizontal Scroll View

Also my main Activity is

```
    public class HorizontalScrollViewActivity extends Activity {
    CenterLockHorizontalScrollview centerLockHorizontalScrollview;
    CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;
    Button btnPrev, btnNext, btnActivity;
    int currIndex = 0;
    private TextView text;

    int data[] = new int[] {200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200};

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {

        {
            add("Jan");
            add("Feb");
            add("Mar");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.e("Ronak","Came at main");


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_scroll_view);
        centerLockHorizontalScrollview = (CenterLockHorizontalScrollview) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, list);
        centerLockHorizontalScrollview.setAdapter(this, customListAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: The basic purpose of the widget is when I click any view in HorizontalScrollView, that view should change its size(width/height) and other views remains in the previous state.

Also please suggest me some good design to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `requestLayout()`. Calling it will make the callee re-measure and re-layout all it's children.

On a side note, is there any particular reason you're using an `Adapter` with a `HorizontalScrollView` (which is not an `AdapterView`)?

The whole idea behind using `Adapter/AdapterView` is view recycling -- `ScrollView`s don't do that. Since you don't use a `ListView` (or other `AdapterView`), using an adapter is overkill.

Also, I don't think putting the content filling logic into a `ScrollView` is a good idea either. You should probably do it in it's child (the one called `parent` in your code). `ScrollViews` are meant to provide easy means of adding scrolling capabilities to any other view -- by simply wrapping it in layout file; extending them with content-aware logic is against their purspose :)

Comment: Can you please tell me, where do I use requestLayout()..
Actually I am making a widget which is using HorizontalScrollView and I want to make this widget similar to ListView. Thats why using Adapter

Comment: you should use `requestLayout()` in your OnClickListener after whatever it is that you do to expand the view. And actually, if you do it using setLayoutParams() you don't have to, 'cause it already does it internally.

Comment: On a side note, going for a horizontal `ListView`, you might wanna check this: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Also, there are several other implementations on GitHub

Comment: Thanks for your time.....

I am using setLayoutParams() in getViewType() method of my custom adapter. Can you please check my Adapter class,I think I may have made some mistake because application is crashing when I am clicking any view of HorizontalScrollView

Comment: What's the error you get? Also, are you trying to update all the items in that cycle by calling getViewType()? because you're actually adding them in addition to those that are already there.

What you should do is just call `v.setLayoutParams(expandedLayoutParams)` in your `OnClickListener`, where `expandedLayoutParams` has the enlarged height -- 150 in your case. No need to re-add everything, so throw away your abc() and changeData() and just store the two versions of `LayoutParams` - for selected and unselected states.